# Why HttpRequestException in VS2015 Simulator but not Emulator

Tags: azure, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I have a WinRt Universal App, and only using VS2015CTP Ultimate (no 3rd party software). The Phone Emulator connects to Azure but the Windows Simulator needs to go through an Http proxy server. I am not inside a corporate firewall. However, if I use Fiddler and have the App use its Http proxy server then the Simulator works. 
I'd like to not use Fiddler at all, so my question is, how do I get the Simulator to make calls to my Azure mobile service without the aid of Fiddler?

I didn't think the code would make a difference as it's the same for both phone and Windows. However, here is the code, and below that is the error.

```
    //In Appl.xaml, VS2015 creates this code:

public static Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient myMobileClient = 
new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient(
"https://nameofmobileservice.azure-mobile.net/",
"***************************");


//I added:

private IMobileServiceTable<MyResultData> GetMyResultDataTable()
        {
            IMobileServiceTable<MyResultData> myResultDataTable = null;
            try
            {
                myResultDataTable = App.myMobileClient.GetTable<MyResultData>();
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
            }
            return myResultDataTable;
        }


//This is the call that fails in Windows simulator, but works in phone emulator:

 public async Task InsertTacticResultData(MyResultData data)
        {
            IMobileServiceTable<MyResultData> myResultDataTable = GetMyResultDataTable();
   try
            {
                await myResultDataTable.InsertAsync(data);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

> Error: An error occurred while sending the request.
>   'MyUniversal.Windows.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application
>   Domain):  Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.DLL'.
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'mymobileservice.azure-mobile.net'    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TransportContext& context)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)
>            Stack trace:
>
> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<>c__DisplayClass10.<<InsertAsync>b__f>d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.d__41.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<InsertAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<TransformHttpException>d__38.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<InsertAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   MyUniversal.Azure.AzureHelper.d__6.MoveNext()

Comment: What is your code? What is the error? Do you have a virus scanner that might be affecting this? Does it work if you run it local rather than through the emulator? The emulator is just a Remote Desktop session whereas the phone is an actual Hyper-v instance with a virtual NIC.

Comment: I added code and error. The Simulator can do regular calls through the browser. Not sure what you mean by "local". However, I could run it as an ASP.NET project as described at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn629482.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Why do you need to use a proxy?

Comment: Then the code works in the Simulator, which is basically the topic of this post - why do I need the proxy?

Comment: One debugging target option is "Local Machine". Have you tried that instead of the Simulator? The DNS/name resolution is failing according to the stack you posted.

Comment: Sorry for delay, I'm on vacation this week. This problem still exists using the Local machine, and running Fiddler to create a proxy host allows it to work. That makes sense since the Simulator looks like a copy of my Local machine in most respects. I suppose I need to set my Azure address via IE allowed sites or something. That will be an annoying task to give users and I doubt Win10 apps will be used as much.

Comment: This issue is something specific to your system configuration or networking. It's not a broad issue with Windows Runtime apps.

Comment: I am looking into the what I need to do the sign the App. I think that may be the issue but haven't had a chance to prove it out.

Comment: Basically I had to run:  
Certutil -addStore TrustedPeople
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I had to run: Certutil -addStore TrustedPeople See 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx